# real analysis proof related to functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

It is asked to prove that, let $f$ be a one to one function if and only if A,B are sub sets of real number $f(A⋂B) = f(A)⋂f(B)$. I have if $f$ is one to one then the results. but I find it hard to prove the reverse part help me please

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ be singletons.

Comment: Have you tried the contrapositive?

Comment: ya but i didn't get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's take Hanul Jeon's suggestion and go contrapositive. Suppose that $f$ is not one-to-one. Then there are two different point $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ but $a\neq b$. Let $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$. Then what is $A\cap B$? What is $f(A\cap B)$? and what is $f(A)\cap f(B)$?